# Custom Paging for the recommendation

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview, stored-procedures

I have around 10000 records in my Sql Server Database, now i want to show 10 records per page, can anyone tell me which of the below 2 ways i should go for:

1. so for this shall i go for GridView (built in paging)
2. Write a Stored Procedure to return records based on the page number as the parameter.

Is there any other good way to go with, which will save the performance while page loading, also won't pressurize my database with the loads of hits.

I remember one of my friend recommended me to go by Stored Procedure way, because that way i can get the records required per page, it will also fastened the page_load process.

Can anyone provide me proper way to go about,

Answer (score 1):

It does not really depend on using stored procedures or not. (using stored procs or ad-hoc queries is a whole different discussion) The important part is here that you only retrieve the records that are necesarry. Whether that is through SP's or ad-hoc queries doesn't really matter.

What you should do is when your grid view loads retrieve the first X records and from there on, fetch the parameters (PageSize and Page). With those two parameters you can then fetch the next records (or previous).

The following articles explain how to do this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6936/Paging-of-Large-Resultsets-in-ASP-NET
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=267
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/gridview/Optimized-Paging-and-Sorting-in-ASP-NET-GridView.aspx